# Place randomly generated numbers into text file

Tags: python

My task was to generate random coordinates (512 of them) within a box that is a dimension of 20x20x20.

The program that views this 3D image, requires XYZ file which is in the format of:

```
1000.000000 #number of coordinates
comment goes here #coment line
H 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 #1st colmun is arbitary - we'll leave it H, 2nd is x vavlue, 3rd value is y value and 4th column is z value.
H 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
H 0.000000 0.000000 2.000000
H 0.000000 0.000000 3.000000
```

So far I have,

```
import random
numpoints=512
L=20
while len(points)<numpoints:
    p = (random.randint(0, L), random.randint(0, L), random.randint(0, L))
    if p not in points:
        points.add(p)
```

This will generate my (x,y,z) coordiantes but the problem I am having is putting it into a text file.

I started with something like this but need some help:

```
with open("question1.xyz","w") as file:
     file.write("\ncomment goes here\n") #this is for the 2nd line in my xyz file
     while len(points)<numpoints:
        p = (random.randint(0, L), random.randint(0, L), random.randint(0, L))
        if p not in points:
            points.add(p)
                    file.write('H %f %f %f\n' % (x, y, z))
```

---

This is what I have to create my out put and put the number of lines is placed on the first line but for some reasoning its not emurating my file

```
#this will put the number of particles as the first line and generate an output file
with open("question2.xyz") as infile:
    with open("q2Output.xyz","w") as outfile:
        for i,line in enumerate(infile):
            if i==0:
                outfile.write('%f\n'%counter)
            else:
                outfile.write(line)
```

I figured out its because of my counter which doesn't exist, but is there a more efficient way of doing it?

Comment: Its not writing my coordinates into the file ideally my file would look something like the above xyz file

Comment: It's not complaining about unknown names x, y, and z?

Comment: What are you getting instead?

Comment: Although this "question" is somewhat different from this other posting of yours (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12700211/randomizing-x-y-z-coordinates-within-a-box), both share the same flaw: a long text and no specific question.  Please try and narrow down things, for example only show a small snippet and ask a specific question such as why does this error message come up, or why doesn't the data gets written to the file etc.

Comment: thanks ive been trying to narrow down and be more specific as i ask

Comment: Do you need unique points or just random points?

Comment: Thats the second part of the question, they are required to be non identical...havent gotten to around that yet..

Answer (score 2):

This could be cleaned up a bit more, but the basic changes made are:

1. adding a `points` container
2. changing `file` to `f` (you want to avoid defining variables with the same name as a Python built-in),
3. changing the format parameter to accept the tuple `p` (it will automatically unpack)
4. making some basic formatting changes.

All in all, you were very close - just a few basic things that needed tweaking.

```
import random

numpoints = 512
L = 20
points = set()

# Open f and write
with open("question1.xyz","w") as f:
    f.write("\ncomment goes here\n") #this is for the 2nd line in my xyz f
    while len(points) < numpoints:
        p = (random.randint(0, L), random.randint(0, L), random.randint(0, L))
        if p not in points:
            points.add(p)
            f.write('H %f %f %f\n' % p)
```

The following isn't any more efficient, but introduces the concept of recursion in order to generate your random point. The previous version works just fine - this is more for fun :)

```
import random

numpoints = 512
L = 20
points = set()

def RandomPoint(points):
    p = (random.randint(0, L), random.randint(0, L), random.randint(0, L))
    if p in points:
      p = RandomPoint(points)
    return p

# Open f and write
with open("question1.xyz","w") as f:
    f.write("\ncomment goes here\n") #this is for the 2nd line in my xyz f
    for point in xrange(0, numpoints):
        p = RandomPoint(points)
        points.add(p)
        f.write('H %f %f %f\n' % p)
```

Comment: Thanks - i really appreciate the help. Since we're on topic I was wondering if you could help me place the number of points as the first line. I attached above what I have so far

Comment: @JohnJones Change the line where you write the comment in the file to `f.write("%d\ncomment goes here\n", % numpoints)`

Comment: See @halex's suggestion in the previous comment - that should work perfectly.

Comment: Thanks but getting an SyntaxError: invalid syntax error highlighitng the %, does it need the be in ".." marks?

Comment: @JohnJones Actually, just remove the `,` so `f.write("%d\ncomment goes here\n" % numpoints)`

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
fh = open('filename', 'w')
fh.write(str(len(points)) + '\n')
fh.write("comment goes here\n")
for point in points:
    fh.write("H %1.6f %1.6f %1.6f\n" % (point[0],point[1],point[2]))
fh.flush()
fh.close()
```

Comment: The crux of your answer (correctly identifying what to write) is correct, but the `with <expression> as <name>` syntax is more pythonic, and just generally safer.

Comment: Ok thanks for the feedback, I have never used with <expression> as <name> before, I shall look into it.